# My simple JQ script toggle is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a website and I have the following issue. When a user selects that he belongs to my university I ask him for his control number and I need to hide the div "institucion_nombre" and show the div "campos"; if he does not belong to this university then I ask him to type the name of the university that he belongs to, that is, I want to show the div "institucion_nombre" and hide the div "campos".

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to website 0.1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script> 
     $(function(){
         $("#amIfromThisUniversity_1").on("change",function(){
         $("#institucion_nombre").toggle(this.selectedIndex==1); 
        });
      $("#amIfromThisUniversity_1").change();  
    });
</script>

<script>

   $(function(){
      $("#amIfromThisUniversity_2").on("change",function(){
      $("#institucion_nombre_2").toggle(this.selectedIndex==1);
      });
      $("#amIfromThisUniversity_2").change(); 
  });

</script>
</head>
   <b><h3>Student 1</h3></b>         
        <li> 
        Name* <input id="Field0"  type="text" />
        Middle Name <input id="Field1"  type="text"/>
            Last name <input id="Field2" type="text"  />
        </li>

       <li>Are you student of this university?
             <select name="amIfromThisUniversity_1">                 
                <option  value="1" selected="selected" >Yes</option>
                <option  value="2" >No</option>    
                </select>    
           </li>

           <div id="institucion_nombre">                    
            <li>
            Write your institution's name 
                <input id="Field5" name="institucion_1" type="text"/>
       </li>
      </div><!--Fin del nombre de la institución-->                 

     <div id="campos">     
       <li>
        Student's control number <input id="Field6" name="expediente_1" type="text" />
       </li>                                
        </div><!--fin de los campos-->

   <hr /> <!--separacion-->

   <b><h3>Student 2</h3></b>         
        <li> 
        Name* <input id="Field0" type="text" />
        Middle Name <input id="Field1" type="text"/>
            Last name <input id="Field2" type="text"/>
        </li>

       <li>Are you student of this university?
             <select name="amIfromThisUniversity_2">                 
                <option   value="1"  selected="selected" >Yes</option>
                <option   value="2"  >No</option>      
                 </select>   
           </li>

           <div id="institucion_nombre_2">                  
            <li>
            Write your institution's name 
                <input id="Field5"  type="text"/>
       </li>
      </div><!--Fin del nombre de la institución-->                 

     <div id="campos2">     
       <li>
            Student's control number <input id="Field6" type="text" />
       </li>                                
        </div><!--fin de los campos-->

   <hr /> <!--separacion-->    
</html>
```

All suggestions and comments are welcome and feel free to modify the code in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CcCbQ/
:)
Cheers

Comment: Your markup is bad... `LI` must be within a `UL` or `OL`, no elements other than an `LI` can be direct children of an `UL` or `OL`.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the wrong selector..

```
<select name="amIfromThisUniversity_1">
```

It has no `id` attribute. So your selector should look like this.

```
$("select[name=amIfromThisUniversity_1]")
```

**[Check This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CcCbQ/5/)**

You can write the same code this way

```
$(function () {
    $("select[name=amIfromThisUniversity_1]").on("change", function () {
        $("#institucion_nombre").toggle(this.selectedIndex == 1);
    }).change();
    
    $("select[name=amIfromThisUniversity_1]").on("change", function () {
        $("#institucion_nombre_2").toggle(this.selectedIndex == 1);
    }).change();
});
```

Also li is generally supposed to be a direct child of `ol` or `ul` . Replace them with divs to have your HTML valid

If your element was

`<select id="amIfromThisUniversity_1">` -**ID selector**  `$("#amIfromThisUniversity_1")`

Your selector would have worked.

Also when you try to replicate the same in the fiddle, you can just paste the code sans the script tags.. Also need to set the framework to jQuery